# MVC Partial View called by Ajax with POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, partial-views

I tried to find an answer for this, but unsuccessfully.

The idea is: when the button is clicked the AddRestaurant method checks if the restaurant already exists in the database. If yes - it links the manager with the restaurant. If no - it creates a new restaurant entry and then links it with the manager.

I have the following code:

JavaScript

```
$("#btnAddRestaurant").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "AddRestaurant",
    data: { id: selectedPlace.place_id, name: selectedPlace.name, lat: selectedPlace.geometry.location.lat(), lng: selectedPlace.geometry.location.lng() },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#addResult").html(data);
        $("#btnAddRestaurant").hide();
        $("#inputLable").hide();
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error in add restaurant");
    }
});
});
```

Actions in controller:

```
public ActionResult AddRestaurant()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AddRestaurant(string id, string name, decimal lat, decimal lng)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Restaurants restaurant =
            _dbRestaurant.Restaurants.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id.Equals(id));
            if (restaurant == null)
            {
                restaurant = new Restaurants
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Name = name,
                    Latitude = lat,
                    Longitude = lng
                };
                _dbRestaurant.Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
                Managers manager = new Managers();
                manager.ManagerId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                manager.RestaurantId = id;
                _dbManager.Managers.Add(manager);
                return PartialView("_LinkRestaurant", restaurant);
            }
            else
            {
                Managers manager = new Managers();
                manager.ManagerId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                manager.RestaurantId = id;
                _dbManager.Managers.Add(manager);
                return PartialView("Index");
            }
        }
        return PartialView("Index");
    }
```

The problem is when I click the button I get the error from the ajax call and a 500 (Internal Server Error). If I change the POST action and make it "GET" it works, but nothing changes in the database. I feel like I am missing something essential. Any help or explanations are very much appreciated.

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means your throwing an exception in the POST method. You need to debug your code to find where it is. You can also you your browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the error.

Comment: And why is your POST signature not just `public PartialViewResult AddRestaurant(Restaurants model)`?

Comment: Check URl wether its linking with your control/action

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for the browser tool hint, I didn't know that. Apparently,the problem was that I was sending the lat and lng as decimals. I changed it to strings and the error went away. Next I noticed nothing was saved in  the db because I forgot to use SaveChanges. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'decimal' in form data - its all just name/value pairs. Most likely you problem was a culture issue - perhaps the decimal separator was a dot when the server is expecting a comma (or vice versa). In any case you should not be changing the parameters to a string. And you really should be changing `lat:` and `lng` in the ajax `data:` option to `Latitude:` and `Longitude:` and then `public PartialViewResult AddRestaurant(Restaurants model)` so that you bind to your model when you post back.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot for the answer! As you suggested, I changed it to `AddRestaurant(Restaurants model)` and made sure that the decimal separator is the comma and now it works.